# mysql select rows with same ids and in order by another column

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
+-------+-----------+------------+
| id    | sequence  | text       |
+-------+-----------+------------+
| 12345 | 01        | Hello, my  | 
| 12345 | 02        | name is CJ | 
| 54321 | 01        | Good morn  | 
| 54321 | 02        | ing! Sup!  | 
+-------+-----------+------------+
```

I am totally lost. There are 2 messages in these rows 1) "Hello, my name is CJ" and 2) "Good morning! Sup!"

How could I display both of these messages by selecting them by IDs and with correct order(sequence)?

So the results would be

> "Hello, my name is CJ"
>
> "Good morning! Sup!"

Comment: have you tried `group_by` ?

Comment: Can you please explain your database schema, that will be helpfull

Comment: You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(text ORDER BY sequence)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(text ORDER BY sequence  SEPARATOR ' ') AS messages
FROM table1
GROUP BY id;
```

**Output**

```
id      messages
12345   Hello, my name is CJ
54321   Good morning! Sup!
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f38d19/5

**GROUP_CONCAT() function**

> MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function returns a string with concatenated
>   non-NULL value from a group.

**Syntax :**

```
GROUP_CONCAT([DISTINCT] expr [,expr ...]
         [ORDER BY {unsigned_integer | col_name | expr}
             [ASC | DESC] [,col_name ...]]
         [SEPARATOR str_val])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

**TRY** `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT id,GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ' ')
FROM tableA
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: `GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR '')` to join directly without commas

Answer (score 0):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(text SEPARATOR ' ')
from table_name
group by id
```